# How do I connect to a Local database using asp.net Mvc4 and visual studio express 2012?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string, localdb, visual-studio-express

I am following the Mvc4 OdeToFood tutorial on Pluralsight, which uses asp-net Mvc4 and visual studio express for web 2012.

I am trying to set up a small local database to hold some information so that I can proceed with the tutorial, but I am having trouble getting the database versions and connection string right, I have never done anything like this before.

I have been going fine until a few days ago when I tried to connect to a Local database.

Unlike in the tutorial, In my web.config file I had no connection string tags, The v11.0 database instance was specified in the tutorial, which from google seems to be a local database used for development purposes. so I looked up what I needed and entered into the Web.config file:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source= 
        (LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial 
        Catalog=OdeToFoodDb;Integrated 
        Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OdeToFoodDb.mdf" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

This would not work for me, so upon more googling I tried:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="OdeToFood" connectionString="Data Source= 
        (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial 
        Catalog=aspnet-OdeToFood;Integrated 
        Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OdeToFood.mdf" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

This initially did work, but when I tried to modify the tables, there was a database version error and I could not use the database crud functionality with the program. I searched as to why this wouldn't work and looked through the error files and I found that once you change a .mdf file to v13.0 (from googling I believe MSSQLLocalDB is v13.0) it cannot be reverted to a v11.0 .mdf version. So I guess vs express 2012 can only use v11.0?

If anyone can help me or point me to somewhere where I can learn how to connect to this database I would be really grateful.

Comment: Open a command prompt windows and type `sqllocaldb i`. It will list out localdbs in your machine. What do you get?
Then you can try `sqllocaldb i <instancename>`. which will give you the state, version, etc.

Comment: Hi, I get 3 versions, v11.0, sqllocaldb and v13.0. v11.0 was running, the other two were not. I am going to do a reinstall of iis express and see if that fixes my problem as this is the last thing I havent done.